# Wamp : How to deploy my application at the root?

Tags: wamp

I have an app deployed on wamp server at the address : `http://localhost/MyApp`
Now I want to deploy my app directly at the root i.e. I want my application to be accessible at the address http://localhost/ only. Is this achievable ?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Sure, just move everything in MyApp/ to the folder one level above it, so if it was (for example) C:\WampServer\htdocs\MyApp just move all of the files to C:\WampServer\htdocs

Comment: Thanks man !! move your comment as an answer so that I accept it !

Comment: It would be better to create a Virtual Host, one for each of yor projects. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) for some help setting up Virtual Hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just move everything in MyApp/ to the folder one level above it, so if it was (for example) C:\WampServer\htdocs\MyApp just move all of the files to C:\WampServer\htdocs